# CRM 2011 Async Service Crashing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

we have a crm 2011 local installation , we were running fine with custom plugins that were sending sms's amongst others ... however after a deployment a  couple of weeks ago ... we are encoutnering an issue. i have removed all waiting or pending workflows and have created a temp workflow that only changes the name of an entity and is run on demand on an entity. a very basic workflow for testing purposes. it however now crashes the async service completely. with no other workflows waiting to be run and im stumped as to the problem. 
here is the event log application error. any help would be greatly appreciated as soon as possible

> Host SERERNAME : failed while monitoring asynchronous operations
>   queue. Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessEntityMoniker..ctor(System.Guid,
>   System.String, Microsoft.Crm.IOrganizationContext)'.    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Caching.StepDescriptionLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key,
>   ExecutionContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Caching.ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key,
>   IOrganizationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCache`2.CreateEntry(TKey key,
>   IOrganizationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key,
>   IOrganizationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.EventOperation.GetPluginAssembly(AsyncExecutionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.EventOperation.InternalExecute(AsyncEvent
>   asyncEvent)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncOperationCommand.Execute(AsyncEvent
>   asyncEvent)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.QueueManager.PoolHandler.ProcessAsyncEvent(AsyncEvent
>   asyncEvent)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.QueueManager.PoolHandler.InvokeHandlerInPool(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Answer (score 0):

A quick google suggests this might be a bug after applying a rollup. It looks like its trying reference a function on a dll that you don't have.

I would suggest.

- Apply the latest CRM rollup.
- Perform a repair installation of CRM.
- Try following the instructions in these links: [problem after installing CRM 2011 rollup 4](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdeployment/thread/fec8ca29-25c1-4332-bff5-85c40da2ac8a), [Can’t Access Organizations after CRM 2011 Update Rollup 10?](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/09/24/crm-2011-update-rollup-10-error-fix/)